# Removable Disk Drives Not Appearing

Tags: windows-vista, sd-card, card-reader, removable

OS: Vista, SP1

My SD/MMC drive does not appear anywhere (MyComputer, Disk Manager). In My Computer the only available drives ar C:\, D:\ and J:. I can no longer view any removable disk drives. When I put my SD  card into its slot, it doesn't get read at all. I can't load pictures from my card to my PC.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already go to device manager and see if the relevant drivers have been installed, if not download them directly if the automatic driver search fails to find a device. You will need to know what hardware the sd card slot is, but if you google your pc manufacturers model number a list of parts should be found

Comment: The auto search does fail to find the device. 
Also, it worked fine up until the other day. I was loading pictures last week and now nothing. 
So, I did a restore from last week, but they are still not apprearing. The only thing I can think of is that I use a Registry Cleaner (CCleaner) - I can't see that impacting though?

Comment: I got nothing! mmm, cCleaner is a long shot but worth a go.

Answer (score 0):

try the **[USB Drive Letter Manager for Windows](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html)**:

> USBDLM is a Windows service that gives
>   control over Window's drive letter
>   assignment for USB drives.

if this doesn't solve the problem, there's also an excellent **[Troubleshooting Guide for USB drives](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtrouble_e.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen computers where the card reader isn't detected until you plug in a card and reboot the computer. Only then is the device detected and drivers installed.